# Retrieve Hidden Object Property Based on Grid Row Item Selected C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datagrid, telerik

I have a DataGrid whose data source is a collection of objects. Now the datagrid is set up to display only a subset of the objects properties. One of the hidden properties is an ID variable which I need to obtain once the row corresponding to that object has been selected.

I know you can listen for row clicks using the SelectIndexChanged event handler....but how is it possible to get at the actual original object correspoding to a row?

Answer (score 1):

> I see you tagged your question with "Telerik".
>
> Are you using a DataGrid or a RadGrid? Yes.

Then specify which event to call in your .aspx file:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            GridLines="None"  
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadGrid1_SelectedIndexChanged" > 
            (...)
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

And declare the event in your .asp file:

```
protected void RadGrid1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    var dataItem = e.Item.DataItem; 
    if (dataItem != null) 
    { 
        int dataItemID = (dataItem As ObjectClassName).ID;
    } 
}
```

*Replace the "ObjectClassName" with the type of your object.

Comment: Well spotted! I'm using a RadGrid.

Comment: I Edited my answer to fit your needs.

Comment: I think you should use the Telerik RadGrid Property DataKeyNames.. provided you a full answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `DataItem` as and then cast the item to the appropriate type and access its properties from there

Quick [link](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/take-row-level-control-of-your-gridview/) shows how this can be accomplished.

Comment: hmm - i'm new to .net what would I assign the DataItem to? I need the syntax!

Comment: eep not sure about RadGrid (saw above comment and noticed the telerik tag)

Comment: I don't think it matters - it's the same as for GridView as this tool is built on the .NET implementation...otherwise how would I do it for a GridView

Comment: added a link that uses GridView, as this is quite a common question if it is indeed for the telerik stuff this should work

Answer (score 0):

When using the Telerik RadGrid you should use the Telerik API's which provide you with 2 properties you can set: DataKeyNames and ClientDataKeyNames.  So long as the column appears in your initial data source, whatever you specify in these 2 properties is accessible both serverside and client side for any row.   Included below how to fetch those values on SelectedIndexChanged (Server-Side) and OnRowSelected (client-side)

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
  OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadGrid1_SelectedIndexChanged">
  <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Id,HiddenVal1,HiddenVal2" ClientDataKeyNames="Id,HiddenVal1,HiddenVal2,clientsideSpecialId">
    <Columns>
      <telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="Select" Text="Select" UniqueName="SelectColumn" />
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact name" DataField="ContactName" />
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="ContactTitle" HeaderText="Contact title" DataField="ContactTitle" />
    </Columns>
  </MasterTableView>
  <ClientSettings>
   <ClientEvents OnRowSelected="RowSelected"/>
  </ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Retrieving the hidden field value server side on selected index changed:

```
    protected void RadGrid1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadGrid1.SelectedItems == null || RadGrid1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
            return;

        var dataItem = RadGrid1.SelectedItems[0] as GridDataItem;
        if (dataItem != null)
        {
            var myId = dataItem.GetDataKeyValue("id").ToString();
            var hiddenfield1 = dataItem.GetDataKeyValue("HiddenVal1").ToString();
            //do stuff
        }
    }
```

and then retrieving the hidden field values client side on row select using ClientEvents OnRowSelected

```
function RowSelected(sender,eventArgs)
{
    var HiddenVal1 = eventArgs.getDataKeyValue("HiddenVal1")
    //do stuff
}
```